# How to fix invaliddefinitionexception when using ObjectMapper on Pojo that has org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I'm not sure if this type of problem was already asked. I couldn't find, so asking

I have a POJO

```
Class A {
    int id;
    Object data;
    //getter and setters
}
```

I set org.json.JSONObject type json into data

**Option 1:**
When I set data to object directly, I get an error from ObjectMapper when doing

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(anInstanceOfA);
```

Error: InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for org.json.JSONObject

{ I assume the problem is between fasterxml and org.json }

**Option 2:**
If I use toString on JSONObject before setting to an instance of A, I see escape character in the output. The output is unacceptable. Can't sacrifice JSON formatting and structure

Is there a way to leave already JSON structured element as-is, with less conversions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915851/could-not-write-json-no-serializer-found-for-class-org-json-jsonobject-and-no-p

Comment: I have seen that and discounted before - why Map etc. Now I changed Map<String,Object> data; + setter/getter and updated my message builder ; and using toMap() when setting payload data. Hope my code reviewers accept it. Is there a overhead of toMap()?